# How do I use a slider in a SwiftUI's MenuBarExtra?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I would like to achieve something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890861/how-to-place-horizontal-slider-in-nsmenu-swift-3-xcode-8) but with SwiftUI and MenuBarExtra:

[image: The desired effect]

Here's the code I have so far:

```swift
MenuBarExtra("Menu Bar App", systemImage: "circle.fill") {    
    Text("Slider below")
    Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 1...100)
    Text("Slider above")
}
```

[image: The result of the code above]

Adding `.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)` *works*, but isn't what I'm looking for.

[image: The result of adding .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)]

Answer (score 0):

This is SwiftUI. You can show any view you want.

However this requires some effort to compose the view.

Quick & dirty, feel free to improve the code

```
struct MenuView: View {
    let devices = ["Headphones", "Multi-Output Device", "Soundflower (2ch)", "Soundflower (64ch)"]
    let selectedDevice = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Group {
                    Row(title: "Volume:")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    Slider(value: .constant(0.2))
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.vertical, 4)
                    Row(title:"Output Device:")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    ForEach(0..<devices.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        Row(title: devices[index], hasCheckmark: index == selectedDevice)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding([.horizontal, .top], 10)
            .frame(maxWidth: 250)
            Divider()
                .frame(maxWidth: 250)
            
            HStack {
                Row(title: "Sound Preferences…")
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading, 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 6)
            .frame(maxWidth: 250)
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    let title : String
    var hasCheckmark = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 4) {
            Group {
                if hasCheckmark {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                } else {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 12)
            Text(title)
        }
    }
}
```